# Bent interior monitor cable — do I need a replacement?

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, cable

I have a Windows 8 Toshiba laptop. The monitor screen needs to be replaced, so I got a new replacement.

I just needed to plug in the only wire it hooks to in the top half of the laptop, but when I got to plug it in I found that the metal that is used to hold it in place once attached to the monitor is bent out of shape so it will not stay in.

It is small enough that if I try to reform it I could snap it or bend something else. My question is: should I or could I, without replacing the laptop, reform the metal carefully, replace the cable, or am I screwed and I need a new laptop?

Please keep in mind this cable is not on the outside of the laptop and is the only cable in the top monitor screen half of the laptop, which is from 2013.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Laptop displays are generally connected via ribbon cables and [ZIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Insertion_Force) or [LIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_insertion_force) connectors.  It's not clear if you bent the cable or the connector?  The connectors generally have plastic latches, so I'm not sure what metal you would be referring to having bent?  It would be useful if you clarified what you bent.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a ribbon cable and not a plug that won't stay in, just use a little masking tape to hold the cable in place.